# Is it possible to access other module export functions within the same file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two functions in the same file, both accessed externally. One of the functions is called by the second.

```
module.exports.functionOne = function(param) {
    console.log('hello'+param);
};

module.exports.functionTwo = function() {
    var name = 'Foo';
    functionOne(name);
};
```

When this gets executed, the call to functionOne is flagged as not defined.

What's the right way to reference it?

One pattern I've found to work is by referencing the file itself.

```
var me = require('./thisfile.js');
me.functionOne(name);
```

... but it feels like there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just simply `module.exports.functionOne()`.

If that's too cumbersome, just do the following:

```
function fnOne() {
    console.log("One!");
}

module.exports.fnOne = fnOne;
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 4):

```
var me = require(module.filename);
me.functionOne(name);
```

or just use exports object itself

```
module.exports.functionOne(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I've been thinking of require is an equivalent of include, import, etc.  If there is another way around it, it might be interesting to see it.  I'm still wet behind the ears with node.

[James Herdmans](http://jherdman.github.com/) [Understanding Node.js "require"](http://jherdman.github.com/2010-04-05/understanding-nodejs-require.html) post really helped me when it came to helping with code organization.  Its definitely worth a look!

```
// ./models/customer.js
Customer = function(name) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = name;

};

// ./controllers/customercontroller.js
require("../models/customer");

CustomerController = function() {
  var self = this;

  var _customers = [
   new Customer("Sid"),
   new Customer("Nancy")
  ];
  self.get() {
   return _customers;
  }
};
```